# Why isn't my ImageView doing anything, at least redrawing?

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, ipad, webview

I made a function that will cycle through images (1.png, 2.png, 3.png, 4.png, 5.png) and display them to a UIImageView. The idea is that I am loading a webpage and I want this imageview to run through this function, basically as a loading icon. However I dont understand why it isn't working, as far as the imageview goes, i dont see anything. Please help! My function's code is below. I know it is something wrong i'm doing here because everything else i test including the webview delegate works just fine.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    for(int c = 1; !webviewLoaded; c++)
    {
        c = c % 6;
        if(c == 6)
            c = 1;
        NSString *numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", c];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:numberString];
        [self.loadingImage setImage:img];
        sleep(1);
    }
});
```

Comment: You should read the documentation on UIImageView. It has animation built right in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are doing UI stuff on a background thread, you should't change UI components from a background thread.

You can change your code as following:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    for(int c = 1; !webviewLoaded; c++)
    {
        c = c % 6;
        if(c == 6)
            c = 1;
        NSString *numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", c];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:numberString];
        [self.loadingImage setImage:img];
        sleep(1);
    }
  }
});
```

This piece of code will work, but is kind of useless and it will give you results not as good as you're expecting because what you are doing is create a separate thread (operation) just to call the UI thread from it and this is not efficient.

What you should do is entirely remove the dispatch like this:

```
   for(int c = 1; !webviewLoaded; c++)
    {
            c = c % 6;
            if(c == 6)
                c = 1;
            NSString *numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", c];
            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:numberString];
            [self.loadingImage setImage:img];
            sleep(1);
    }
```

This will also work, but make sure you have those files `@"%d.png` added to your project.

And because you are not familiar with `GCD` here is a [good tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial)

Comment: @MarcusAdams Yes he could, but he posted a piece of code and I don't know how he is using it, so I posted a solution to that code, but from what I think he is trying to do (simply load some images from the project) there's no need for any kind of `dispatch` because there is no heavy processing on the image or other computing that's why I added the second piece of code ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help and your resource. FYI, your suggestion was only a partial solution. In order to make it work, you need to put the second block around only the UI that is changing be I am still appreciative for you taking the time